# Why java app docker image based on eclipse-temurin JRE takes 335Mb?

Tags: java, docker, dockerhub, eclipse-temurin

I'm using [temurin 17-jre-jammy docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/tags?page=1&name=17-jre-jammy) as a base and it should take ~90Mb of space.

[image]

My app currently takes 74Mb so resulting image must be around 164Mb. But it is 335Mb.

When I'm checking layers on Docker Desktop it says that 17-jre-jammy takes ~190Mb which corresponds with the 17 JDK
[image]

[image]

Why JRE layer takes 190Mb instead of 47?) How to fix that?

I tried to find sizes of layers for the 17-jre and on the docker hub it is correct: [Image hierarchy eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/eclipse-temurin/17-jre-jammy/images/sha256-55cfa512c57e9365b50c477dcf0026718d8001e91fd333044b084234e1baef72?context=explore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the source of confusion.

JDK and JRE size on the eclipse temurin site specifies the size of compressed files. After unarchiving it will take more place.

[image]

Same thing relates to docker [17-jre-jammy image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/tags?page=1&name=17-jre-jammy) - 90Mb it is compressed size of the image (it is mentioned just above the size). And after image downloading docker always performs extracting.

So I was referring to compressed size of docker and JDK/JRE while thinking it should be final size.